# My JQuery ipify API call Using XMLHttpRequest is returning a Status 405 Error

Tags: jquery, xmlhttprequest

This is the code for my `http://api.ipify.org` call:

```
    function getInfo(website)
    {

      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      //change this string to the lambda_insertPromoter string.
      // fuckCORS + 
      var url = website;
      console.log("getInfo");
      //alert(data);        
      xhr.open("POST", url, true);
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");
      xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With","XMLHttpRequest");

      xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

            var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            console.log(json);
            var ip_address = json.ip;
            console.log(ip_address)
            return ip_address;

          }
          else if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status >= 400 && this.status < 500)
          {
            console.log(this);
            console.log("getInfo: readyState == 4 && status >= 400 && status < 500");
          }
          else if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status >= 500)
          {
            console.log("getInfo: readyState == 4 && status >= 500");
          }
        }

      xhr.send();

    }

    var ip_address_2 = getInfo("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.ipify.org/?format=json&callback=?");

    alert(ip_address_2);
```

When I run this request I get this response:

```
XMLHttpRequest { onreadystatechange: onreadystatechange(), readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, responseURL: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.ipify.org/?format=json&callback=?", status: 405, statusText: "Method Not Allowed", responseType: "", response: "" }
```

The response I'm getting is a status 405 code which means that the site is getting the request but it's not working.

What changes should I make to get the IP address I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What [HTTP 405](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405) actually means is *method not allowed* which means the url you're trying to reach via `POST` does not allow `POST`. Use `GET`. Also, the way you're trying to get the return values: `var ip_address_2 = ...` will not work because you're making an HTTP request, which is asynchronous, which means `alert(ip_address_2)` will always alert `undefined`.

Enter [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)/[await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

Basically, you wrap your code in a Promise and that's what you return. Then outside you *await* for that promise to resolve/reject and then you'll have your value in `ip_address_2`.

Notice I also wrapped the code that invokes `getInfo` in an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) with (important) the `async` keyword, since `await` can only be used inside `async` functions.

HIH

```js
 function getInfo(website) {
     console.log("getting info...");
     return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("get", website, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With","XMLHttpRequest");

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
               var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
               var ip_address = json.ip;
               resolve(ip_address); //<-- this is how you return (on success) from inside a Promise
            }
            else if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status >= 400 && this.status < 500)
            {
               reject(this.status); //<-- this is how you return (on failure) from inside a Promise
               console.log(this.status);
               console.log("getInfo: readyState == 4 && status >= 400 && status < 500");
            }
            else if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status >= 500)
            {
               reject(this.status);
               console.log("getInfo: readyState == 4 && status >= 500");
            }
          }
         xhr.send();
       });
    }

(async ()=>{
    var ip_address_2 = await getInfo("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.ipify.org/?format=json&callback=?");
    console.log(`got info: ${ip_address_2}`);
})();
```